# VB.NET - AddressOf with parameters

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, dispatcher

Consider this code:

```
Dim MyDispatcher = Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
Public NormalUpdateThread As System.Threading.Thread
Private Delegate Sub UpdateUIDelegate()
```

I call my method as

```
MyDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, New UpdateUIDelegate(AddressOf doProgressbarStuff))
```

and the function doProgressbarStuff

```
Public Sub doProgressbarStuff()
        customprogressbar1.Increment(1)
        customprogressbar1.Content = "Elapsed Time: " & GetTime(elapsedSeconds) & " | " & " Remaining Time:GetRemainingtime() | " & progressBarEdit1.Value & " of " & My.Settings.maindatatable.Rows.Count & " Products Updated |" & " Completion:" & Math.Round((progressBarEdit1.Value / My.Settings.maindatatable.Rows.Count), 3) * 100 & "%"
      End Sub
```

The code above is working just fine. The problem is I've written a new doProgressbarStuff function that takes three parameters and I am not sure how to call it using Addressof or make it function in the same way as the above doProgressbarStuff function but with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of overrides available for BeginInvoke

[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You might be looking at using [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Method (Delegate, DispatcherPriority, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647500%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Executes the specified delegate asynchronously **with the specified
>   arguments**, at the specified priority, on the thread that the
>   Dispatcher was created on.